# Is there a way to run a PHP file from our domain with AJAX on Stack Snippets?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Is there an (easy) way to go around the cross-origin restriction in order to get an AJAX example to work in a Stack Snippet? Or alternatively, a way to upload on Stack Snippet, the php file we want to run with Ajax. The purpose is to get the full context of the question in an SO snippet ([like here for this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45863567/6214222)) ?

My understanding of same origin policy is mainly the result of reading the [wikipedia page on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), so a concise complementary explanation on the same origin policy principle and/or the way it is used on OS might be needed ...

For example, I do not get why [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery/34592395#34592395)

> [image]

gets blocked by a multi-origin error

> [image]...

Comment: I was mistaken, please don't repost this on the main site. It seems the question here is about "How to bypass Same-Origin policy issue on Stack Snippets"? Unfortunately, it's sandboxed to prevent "evil script". Please read [How is my browser protected from XSS in Stack Snippets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239560) for the reason.

Comment: @Andrew yes exactly, this is what the first sentence of my question says, the rest is what I tried to put together to figure it out and that seem to result in 8 votes for not researching ! quite frustrating I must say ...

Comment: @Andrew I'll have to take more time to look into the link you provided but is the short answer to my question = it is not possible to provide a php file (from our own domain our that we could upload somewhere) to be run by ajax, in a SO snippet (to have the whole context of a problem directly in the question) ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry that people did not read your question carefully enough. It was correct to ask here, since it is about a feature of Stack Overflow itself. The good news is, downvotes on Meta have no effect on your reputation.

Comment: @Cody thanks for saying this ... always good to know I'm not totally stupid ... ;-} ... the number of down votes decreased, does that mean the people who initial downvoted realised the read to quick and took their vote off or is that because other people upvoted it ?

Comment: Both. The split is now +6/-6, so two of the people reversed (or removed) their downvotes, but a bunch of new people upvoted.

Comment: Every time someone posts an image of code I kick a puppy. Why do you hate puppies?

Comment: @will *you* kick puppies so *you* take responsibility for that... If you give me a good reason for not posting image of code, I 'll take it into account ( I put an image of the snipet because when I posted the question, I had just made the snippet by editing another question and it was not accepted yet) ...

Comment: Well, to be serious, here's a bunch of great reasons why that's generally a bad idea (tho they might not apply in this case... the puppy kicking is just instinct at this point, I've been traumatized too many times...) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: "tho they might not apply in this case." exactly ! ;-P ... "traumatized" ... you mean by puppies ??? ... >-)

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way. You will not have any means to load arbitrary code from a domain not controlled by Stack Exchange, for our safety.

If you really want those AJAX calls to work, mock them: (I was tempted to only show an image but I don't want have Will kick any more puppies)

```js
/* mock ajax calls */

$.ajax = function(opt) {
  // mock here what you want
  if (opt.url === '1.php') {
    opt.success({data:'fubar'});
  }
  
  return { abort: function() { console.log('abort called')} };
}

/* end mock ajax calls */

function libAjax(){
  var req;
  function start(){

    req =  $.ajax({
      url: '1.php',
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
      }
    });
  }

  function stop(){
    req.abort();
  }

  return {start:start,stop:stop}
}

var obj = libAjax();

$(".go").click(function(){
  obj.start();
})

$(".stop").click(function(){
  obj.stop();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" class="go" value="GO!" >
   <input type="button" class="stop" value="STOP!" >
```

Comment: I'll take this no as an answer (since it seems I have to...;-}...) but I don't get how it is not possible to prevent php files from doing what could be harmfull to the server

Comment: I'll happily take any complementary info about what "mocking an ajax call" means (in my defence, please consider I'm a froggy ...) I find plenty of references for "how to" but nothing about what it means (in short)

Comment: Did you find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665812/what-is-mocking? *In short, mocking is creating objects that simulate the behaviour of real objects.* Let me know if you need more on that @v2belleville

Comment: @v2belleville it wouldn't make much sense to upload anything even if it wre safe. If you are debugging a front-end app, the ajax response should be mocked anyway to properly isolate the logic you want to debug.

Comment: my question is about [getting the snipet of this question to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45863567/6214222)  I only mentioned the above snipet because I could not understand why it was not working, since I still do not know why it was not working in the first place I cant figure out how to use the suggested solution to get mine to work ...

Comment: @rene + yivi did not see your comment before sending my last one, will look into this when its not the end of the day for me. be assured I'll be back to you guys if needed ... ;)